# Why does sp_getapplock not return control immediately?

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking

When two users in my application run the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CopyForm](@varId as uniqueidentifier)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnLock INT
    BEGIN try
        EXEC @returnLock = Sp_getapplock
        @Resource = 'CopyFormLock',
        @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
        @LockOwner = 'Session'
 
        IF @returnLock <> 0
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR (
            'the operation is occupied by another user, wait a few minutes',
            16,1
            )
            RETURN
        END
        
        --do stuff

        EXEC @returnLock = Sp_releaseapplock
        @Resource = 'CopyFormLock',
        @LockOwner = 'Session'
    END try
    BEGIN catch
        IF @returnLock = 0
        BEGIN
            EXEC @returnLock = Sp_releaseapplock
                @Resource = 'CopyFormLock',
                @LockOwner = 'Session'
        END
    END catch
END
GO
```

The first user who locks the procedure executes it and then unlocks it. The second user waits and only after the first user removes the lock, the second user gets the error "the operation is occupied by another user, wait a few minutes".
I do not understand why the error is not output for the second user immediately, and I have to wait for the first one.
Explain plz where I made a mistake, and how to make the error be displayed immediately?

Comment: What is the value of `@returnLock` when this occurs? I suspect it is `1`, which is *not* a failure: *"**The lock was granted successfully** after waiting for other incompatible locks to be released."*

Comment: Also, as you aren't passing the value of `@LockTimeout`, what is the value of the `@@LOCK_TIMEOUT` setting?

Comment: `IF @returnLock <> 0` Read the documentation. Your single error message can be very misleading. Worse is that you catch errors and eat them - the procedure caller will have no idea that any error occurred.

Comment: If you want the attempt to get the app lock to return instantly if the lock is unavailable rather than wait then pass a `@LockTimeout` of `0` as [the fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) states.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues here:

- The result of `sp_getapplock` is always less than 0 in a failure. If it is equal to `1` then it just means it had to wait.
- If you want the procedure to immediately bail-out if the lock is held then pass `@LockTimeout = 0`.
- Use `THROW` instead of `RAISERROR`.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CopyForm](@varId as uniqueidentifier)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @returnLock INT
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC @returnLock = sp_getapplock
        @Resource = 'CopyFormLock',
        @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
        @LockOwner = 'Session',
        @LockTimeout = 0;
 
        IF @returnLock < 0
        BEGIN
            THROW
              50001,
              'the operation is occupied by another user, wait a few minutes',
              1;
        END;
        
        --do stuff

        EXEC @returnLock = sp_releaseapplock
        @Resource = 'CopyFormLock',
        @LockOwner = 'Session';
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @returnLock = 0
        BEGIN
            EXEC @returnLock = sp_releaseapplock
                @Resource = 'CopyFormLock',
                @LockOwner = 'Session';
        END;
        THROW;
    END CATCH

go
```